# How to add an html block on all admin pages

Tags: admin, layout, adminhtml

To add an html section on all pages of admin panel using a separate module i have created a sepetate layout 
customercare.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <reference name="footer">
    <block type="adminhtml/template" template="customercare/quickbox.phtml" name="footer_quick_box" as="footer_quick_box" />
</reference>
</layout>
```

I have added few texts in "customercare/quickbox.phtml" but its not showing on the any of the pages.

Extension config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Customercare>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </My_Customercare>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customercare>
                <class>My_Customercare_Helper</class>
            </customercare>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <customercare>
                <class>My_Customercare_Block</class>
            </customercare>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customercare>
                    <file>customercare.xml</file>
                </customercare>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**handle** missing in your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" template="customercare/quickbox.phtml" name="footer_quick_box" as="footer_quick_box" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And you need to add the below code in

> root/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/footer.phtml

```
<?php $this->getChildhtml('footer_quick_box')?>
```

If you don't want edit any code phtml file, then use `before_body_end`

i.e.,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" template="customercare/quickbox.phtml" name="footer_quick_box" as="footer_quick_box" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```